# How to install Etherpad on Shared Linux Hosting?

Tags: linux, shared-hosting, etherpad

I have a linux shared hosting with cpanel, I want to install Etherpad (http://etherpad.org/) on it. Please tell me steps how to do it?

Comment: If you've found the solution, kindly share it.

Comment: I have followed [this tutorial on DigitalOcean Community](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-etherpad-for-production-with-node-js-and-mysql-on-a-vps) to install Etherpad on my server.
Edit: I am using VPS now.