# How to install etherpad-lite on cPanel (shared hosting)

Tags: node.js, cpanel, etherpad

My hoster allows to install node-js applications by using cPanel. I tried to install [etherpad-lite](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite), but once visiting the URL of the app, the app isn't working, just this notice is thrown out *"It works! NodeJS 11.15.0"*.

Here's a screenshot of the cPanel:

[image: screenshot of cpanel section for node.js apps]

As you can see, there's no package.json file in the directory. Maybe here's the issue? I just cloned the git repo as indicated in the [installation guide](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite#installation), which results in the following file structure on my server:

[image]

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394117/how-to-install-etherpad-on-shared-linux-hosting) very similar question, but since it was posted in 2015 and still has no suitable answers, I issued a new and more specific question with more information.
I hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Application start up file should be "src/bin/run.sh" (from root folder). This will install all the dependencies and start the server.